# looping back in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having trouble looping back in java (netbeans).
I have to create 4 classes and the "looping" part is the only unfinished part.

```
package question.pkg1;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shape {

void secondclass(){

System.out.println("Choose the shape you want to find the Perimeter and Area of: ");
System.out.println("1. Square "
                         + " 2. Rectangle ");
System.out.println("**To select sqauare, enter 1**");
System.out.println("**To select rectangle, enter 2**");

int value;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 value = input.nextInt();

if (value == 1) {
    Square Squareclass = new Square();
    Squareclass.thirdclass();}

else if (value == 2) {
    Rectangle Rectangleclass = new Rectangle();
    Rectangleclass.fourthclass();}

else{
    System.out.println("**Error: Please enter a correct value!**");
}

}}
```

Comment: Which loop constructs have you learned about?

Comment: for, while, do, else.

Comment: Where's the collection, the range or whatever you need to loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use a do.. while loop like:

```
do {
    //read value
    //process based on value
} while (value > 0 && value <= 2);//assuming your valid values are 1,2 and if it is let user continue further.
```